# Why should maintain order to write these following CSS properties?

Tags: css, border, border-image

We know from that if want to apply different color properties to any single element then the last properties will be applicable like this:

```
color: green;
color: blue;
color: yellow;
```

so the color of the text will be yellow as usual. But what is the problem in my case stated below???

If I write this order the effect works properly:

```
border-left: 7px solid;
border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, yellowgreen, green);
border-image-slice: 1;
```

But If I write this order the effect doesn't work properly:

```
border-image-slice: 1;
border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, yellowgreen, green);
border-left: 7px solid;
```

or,

```
border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, yellowgreen, green);
border-left: 7px solid;
border-image-slice: 1;
```

or any other order except the first order I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only code that will not work in your list is this one:

```
border-image-slice: 1;
border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, yellowgreen, green);
border-left: 7px solid;
```

And it has nothing to do with `border-left` but it's related to `border-image-slice` that should be defined **after** `border-image` because `border-image` is the shorthand property that include the `border-image-slice` so if defined later, it will override the slice with the initial value since you are not defining any slice inside your `border-image`

examples to illustrate the issue and to show that `border-left` can be placed anywhere without any issue

```css
.box {
  margin: 5px;
}

.b1 {
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, yellowgreen, green);
  
  border-left: 7px solid;
}

.b2 {
  border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, yellowgreen, green);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  
  border-left: 7px solid;
}

.b3 {
  border-left: 7px solid;
  
  border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, yellowgreen, green);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

.b4 {
  border-left: 7px solid;
  
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, yellowgreen, green);
}

.b5 {
  border-left: 7px solid;
  
  border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, yellowgreen, green) 1;
}

.b6 {
  border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, yellowgreen, green);

  border-left: 7px solid;
  
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

.b7 {
  border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, yellowgreen, green) 1;
  
  border-left: 7px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box b1">
  no border here
</div>
<div class="box b2">
  A border here
</div>
<div class="box b3">
  A border here
</div>
<div class="box b4">
  no border here
</div>
<div class="box b5">
  A border here, the slice is inside the border-image
</div>

<div class="box b6">
  A border here
</div>

<div class="box b7">
  A border here,  the slice is inside the border-image
</div>
```

To avoid such issue use `border-image-source` instead of `border-image` and all the combination will work since there is no shorthand involved

```css
.box {
  margin: 5px;
  
  /* you can try any order and it will always work */
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(180deg, yellowgreen, green);
  border-left: 7px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  a border here
</div>
```